# Insert span at the bottom of image within another span tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying my best to insert a span tag caption within an image.

Both are within a paragraph and span tag.

How do I get the the lorem ipsum text to appear at the bottom of the image as its caption ??

```
<p style="text-align: justify;">
 <span style="color: #000000;"> 
  <img class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-8072" width="1200" height="1750" src="https://static.groupon.sg/83/75/1373877177583.jpg" scale="0">
  <span style="display: inline-block;vertical-align:bottom;"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
 </span>
</span>
</p>
```

Comment: PS `pagespeed_url_hash` is not a valid HTML attribute

Comment: Are you set on doing it this way? or are you open to doing it a different way?

Comment: My hands are tied.. and have to do this with the available tags.. it a really old wordpress website

Comment: Do not add back in irrelevant tags, they were removed on purpose.

Comment: @cimmanon Is that why you voted the question down??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have specified you can't alter the HTML *which would be the best option*. You can just alter the CSS to make one the spans behave like a div with a relative position, then use z-indexing to stack the span tag with the caption over the img.

**CSS**

```
p span{
  display:inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
p span img{
  width: 300px;
  height: auto;
}
p span span{
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px;
  z-index: 10;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,.7);
}
```

[Example JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qszs11xf/)

Comment: z-index is not needed at all. It's best avoided in favor for a better HTML formatting.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.imgCaption{
  display: inline-block;      /* Needed since It's a SPAN */
  position: relative;         /* to contain the absolute caption */
  text-align: justify;    
  width: 33.333%;             /* Demo only */
}
.imgCaption img{
  vertical-align:top;         /* Remove gaps caused by inline elements */
  width: 100%;                /* Adjust to parent */
}
.imgCaption > span{
  position: absolute;          /* We want it at the bottom so, needed */
  color: #fff;                 /* Always use bright colors for overlay captions */
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); /* Optional */
  bottom:0; left:0; right:0;   /* Bottom, and enlarge to full */
  padding:24px;                /* Make the text breathe */
}
```

```html
<span class="imgCaption">
 <img src="https://static.groupon.sg/83/75/1373877177583.jpg" alt="pasta">
 <span> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.</span>
</span>
```

To recap: don't use inline styles! Make your life easier!
Add a **class** to your elements you want to target and use a stylesheet.